How do I keep Child Processes open after program termination in Eclipse by default?
I'm using Test NG and Selenium in Eclipse for automated testing. When a test execution is finished, Eclipse kills all child processes. (since Eclipse 4.18
This means the Eclipse also kills all the browsers that were opened by the suite, which prevents further testing in the browser.
Since Eclipse 4.19 there is an option in launch configurations to turn off this behaviour, but it is always on by default for every new configuration. Since we make hundreds of launch configurations per person, it's not really feasible for us to modify it for every single launch configuration.
It's possible to create default JVM parameters for Test NG, but I'm not sure what the JVM parameter for this would look like, or even if it's possible to use that to make it default to off. Exporting the launch configuration I found that the name of the parameter in question is org.eclipse.debug.core.TERMINATE_DESCENDANTS.
There doesn't seem to be any other setting options provided by the test NG plugin that would work.
Creating a TestNG launch configuration prototype is also not an option, as eclipse/the testNG plugin does not have that option for test NG run configurations.
Other possible solutions might be to somehow decouple the browsers as child processes within the code, or to protect them from being terminated through code in the test itself, but I'm not sure how we could go about this.
Also, there was an eclipse bug report which resulted in adding the option to turn off the automatic termination, but they decided to make it per run configuration rather than a project/workspace wide preference. The related commit can be found in comment #20.
